# Contact form 7 + POPUP + date time picker, WP Elementor

Tags: contact-form-7, elementor

Datetimepicker doesn't want to work only in popup.
If i insert Contact form 7 without popup it's working.
Maybe someone has encountered something like this?
I think it doesn't work because popup injects in the end of body. But how to fix it i just don't know.

[POP UP OPTIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N85BP.png)

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please take the [tour] and read how to [ask], an [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question, then look at the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. To solve the problem, create an HTML element in the pop-up form and add the following lines of code to it:
date-time-picker-for-contact-form-7/assets/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js
date-time-picker-for-contact-form-7/assets/js/datetimepicker.js
You can take the upper lines on the working page with inspectelement, select the date and time, and copy and paste the lines related to the two upper js files.
After saving and viewing the pop-up page, you will see that the date and time selection section will work.